# My django models are returning serialised data in json format for my view but i also want a string representation for my admin. How do i do that

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-admin

My django models are returning serialised data in json format for my view but i also want a string representation for my admin. How do i do that

```
class Perfumes(models.Model):
  brandsection = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  trending = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  price = models.IntegerField()
  color = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
  def serialize(self):
    return {
    "id": self.id, "brandsection": self.brandsection,"brand": self.brand, "price": self.price,"color": self.color,"description": self.description}

class PerfumesImages(models.Model):
  entry = models.ForeignKey(Perfumes, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="perfumesphoto")
  images = models.ImageField(upload_to='Perfumes', verbose_name='Image')
  def serialize(self):
    return {
      "id": self.id,
      "entry": {"entryid" : self.entry.id, "brandsection" : self.entry.brandsection, "brand" : self.entry.brand, "price" : self.entry.price, "color" : self.entry.color,"description" : self.entry.description},
      "images": self.images.url
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format your post and clarify what you mean by 'string representation'.   Would a ```json.dumps(<your dictionary>)``` be sufficient or is there special formatting involved?

Comment: I am sorry about the poor code format, i dont know how to format it well here

Comment: I am having challenges to edit my code to format it well

Comment: My django models is returning this

Comment: def serialize(self): return { "id": self.id, "entry": {"entryid" : self.entry.id, "brandsection" : 
                   self.entry.brandsection, "brand" : self.entry.brand, "price" : self.entry.price, "color" : self.entry.color,"description" : self.entry.description}, "images": self.images.url }

Comment: i am retuning serialised data  but i also want to return  a string for my Django admin interface

Comment: Something line ``` def __str__(self): return self.entry```